# Looping through an array in an aggregate function

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

In the documents of my collection, I have a big json object, in which I have nested arrays and other json objects.
In a specific array, I have a certain number of objects that I can't predict in advance as it varies depending on the document, and I need to get the value of a field from all the objects of this array. So I would like to do a loop in this array to get all my values.

Here's how my array looks like (simplified) :

```
"columns":[{"subDropdownLists":[],"type":"Integer","restLabel":"m_visits"},{"subDropdownLists":[],"type":"Integer","restLabel":"m_unique_visitors"},{"subDropdownLists":[],"type":"Integer","restLabel":"m_users"}]
```

I need to get the 'restLabel' field. Ideally, like that, concatenated in a unique field :
"restLabel" : 'm_visits, m_unique_visitors, m_users'.

At the moment, in my aggregate function, I have that :

```
"column1" : { $arrayElemAt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$analyse.analyseElements.columns', 0 ] }, 0 ] },
```

But it obviously only gets me the first json of the array.
(For info, the 'columns' field in also in json 'analyseElements' in an array 'analyse'...)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You can try using the [Query Projection on Array Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-on-embedded-documents-in-an-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$columns"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      restLabel: {
        $push: {
          $concat: [
            "$columns.restLabel"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "restLabel": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$restLabel",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              ",",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      restLabel: {
        $substr: [
          "$restLabel",
          1,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6bQOpK8XpWI)